# How to create connection from iReport Designer 4.5 to JasperReports server Repository

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I am trying to create jasper server connectivity from iReport Designer 4.5 using Window-> JasperReports server Repository -> When prompting, Added jasperserver URL and credentials. Its added to the repository but getting an error message "Error: ;nested exception is: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad envelope tag: html" .Could anyone please guide me on how to resolve this error.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your issue is due to a defect, that they have fxed in their latest JasperReports Server version (`4.5`). JasperReports Server `4.2` has a servlet filter (UploadMultipartFilter) in `web.xml` that consumes multipart requests, which disrupts Axis (the web service library that is used by iReports). This causes the error.

So to fix this you can either upgrade to their `4.5` release or do the following modifications to your configuration files located in `<jasperserver[-pro] root>/WEB-INF/web.xml` and comment out the following lines:

```
<!--
    <filter>
        <filter-name>multiPartHelperFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.common.UploadMultipartFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>multiPartHelperFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
-->
```

By adding the `<!--` and `-->` before and after the Filter and filter-mapping tags)

And then edit `WEB-INF/applicationContext-security-web.xml` by adding the filter to the chain that maps:

```
...
/** = httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter, uploadMultipartFilter, ${bean.loggingFilter},
${bean.userPreferencesFilter}, ${bean.authenticationProcessingFilter},
${bean.userPreferencesFilter}, ${bean.basicProcessingFilter},
requestParameterAuthenticationFilter, JIAuthenticationSynchronizer,
anonymousProcessingFilter, exceptionTranslationFilter, filterInvocationInterceptor,
switchUserProcessingFilter, iPadSupportFilter
... 

<bean id="uploadMultipartFilter" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.common.UploadMultipartFilter"/>
```

By adding "uploadMultipartFilter" at the second position of the filter chains for URI /** (normally the last one in the bean filterChainProxy) and to reference that new filter by adding the bean with id uploadMultipartFilter below the bean filterChainProxy.

Comment: Hi, I have JasperServer Professional 3.1.0.1 [cannot upgrade to higher version] and trying to integrate iReport Designer 4.5. This error is coming up in iReport Designer 3.0.0 version as well. I am unsure if there is any setting to connect to JasperReports Server from iReport Designer.Please help.

Comment: Hi, In JasperServer Professional 3.1.0.1 I couldnt find the file applicationContext-security-web.xml. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to establish connection between iReport4.5/iReport4.5.1 to JasperReport Server 4.5.  After I installed the JasperServer I started the server accessed thru the browser and copied the URL and added JasperReports Server URL section, for username and password I used the superuser account to establish the connection. It did not throw any error message.  Try to use the closest versions for both your designer and server... Hope this helps....